# Return last value with recursion - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi all I have following data:

```
const section = {
  fileds: [
    { id: "some Id-1", type: "user-1" },
     {
      child: [
        { id: "some Id-2", type: "user-2" },
        { fileds: [{ id: "kxf5", status: "pending" }] },
        { fileds: [{ id: "ed5t", status: "done" }] }
      ]
    },
    {
      child: [
        { id: "some Id-3", type: "teacher" },
        { fileds: [{ id: "ccfr", status: null }] },
        { fileds: [{ id: "kdpt8", status: "inProgress" }] }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

and following code:

```
const getLastIds = (arr) =>
  arr.flatMap((obj) => {
    const arrayArrs = Object.values(obj).filter((v) => Array.isArray(v));
    const arrayVals = Object.entries(obj)
      .filter(([k, v]) => typeof v === "string" && k === "id")
      .map(([k, v]) => v);
    return [...arrayVals, ...arrayArrs.flatMap((arr) => getLastIds(arr))];
  });

console.log(getLastIds(section.fileds));

// output is (7) ["some Id-1", "some Id-2", "kxf5", "ed5t", "some Id-3", "ccfr", "kdpt8"]
```

My code doing following, it printing in new array all ids.

It's working but I don't need all ids.

I need to return only last `id` in array and I should use recursion.
The output should be

**(4) [" "kxf5", "ed5t", "ccfr", "kdpt8"]**

P.S. here is my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-jackson-on10mo) in codesandbox

Is there a way to solve this problem with recursion? Please help to fix this.

Comment: why not use same named properties for children? this would make recursion easier.

Comment: Data comes from backend.

Comment: btw, why not `'some Id-1'` as result?

Comment: @NinaScholz because it seems like homework. There are [multiple questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72014784/return-necessary-value-with-recursion-javascript/72015383) being asked with `section` `fileds` and trying to get an array of id's

Comment: Nice catch @0stone0

Comment: Why "with recursion"? Insistence on a particular methodolgy (i.e. using recursion) is a big hint that this is a homework question. Is it?

Comment: If there is a better idea than recursion I will be happy to hear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `reduce`.

```
function getLastIds (value) {
    return value.reduce((prev, cur) => {
        if (cur.id) {
            return [ ...prev, cur.id ];
        } else {
            let key = ('child' in cur) ? 'child' : 'fileds';
            return [ ...prev, ...getLastIds (cur[key]) ]
        }
    }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if a certain key exists and take this property for mapping `id` if `status` exists.

```js
const
    getValues = data => {
        const array = Object.values(data).find(Array.isArray);
        return array
            ? array.flatMap(getValues)
            : 'status' in data ? data.id : [];
    },
    section = { fileds: [{ id: "some Id-1", type: "user-1" }, { child: [{ id: "some Id-2", type: "user-2" }, { fileds: [{ id: "kxf5", status: "pending" }] }, { fileds: [{ id: "ed5t", status: "done" }] }] }, { child: [{ id: "some Id-3", type: "teacher" }, { fileds: [{ id: "ccfr", status: null }] }, { fileds: [{ id: "kdpt8", status: "inProgress" }] }] }] },
    result = getValues(section);

console.log(result);
```